# Ubuntu Studio 19.04 keeps resetting refresh rate

Tags: xfce, amd-graphics, 19.04, gpu, ubuntu-studio

The default refresh rate Ubuntu seems to use causes flickering on my screen. But setting it to 50 makes everything work perfectly. The problem is it keeps resetting the refresh rate after waking from sleep or restarting. This is stock Ubuntu Studio with an AMD card.

I've heard of this happening from a bug in compiz, but `dpkg -l` does not show it installed.

Comment: See my answer below about filing this as a bug report, but in the future, please specify the exact hardware showing the issue. This will be helpful in the bug report as well.

Answer (score 0):

At this time, I believe this may be a bug. Please file a bug report with the following command from the terminal:

```
ubuntu-bug xfce4-settings
```

Unfortunately, that does not fix your issue, but is the first step to getting this resolved for everyone. This may already be fixed in Xfce 4.14-pre1 (currently being tested in Ubuntu 19.10 by both Xubuntu and Ubuntu Studio), but there is no way of knowing for sure.